# Subject and from fields are not coming well

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have created a shell script that check status for mysql and send a mail if it is not running.The script is running well but from and subject are not coming well in mail.

FROM_ADDRESS is coming as `root` and subject is coming `blank`.

```
#!/bin/bash
TO_ADDRESS="abdul@gmail.com"
FROM_ADDRESS="StatusUpdate"
SUBJECT="MySQL Server Status Update"
SENT_DATE=`date`

# This file will hold all the contents that needed to be sent in mail.
BODY_FILE="contents.log"
COMMAND=`which sendmail`
CC_LIST="navodaya05@gmail.com"

# Remove the file if exists
rm $BODY_FILE

echo "Hi All"$'\n' >> $BODY_FILE
echo "This is MySQL Server status update.Status Checked At $SENT_DATE." >> $BODY_FILE

# The below line will check status for mysql if it is running it wil return output  "mysqlstart/running,"
SERVER_STATUS_TO_CHECK=`service mysql status | grep 'mysql' | awk '{print $1 $2}'`

# Check status and if server is not running and send mail
if [ "$SERVER_STATUS_TO_CHECK" == "mysqlstart/running," ]; then
    echo "MySQL is Running"$'\n'>> $BODY_FILE
else
    echo "MySQL Server is not running.Please investigate ASAP."$'\n' >> $BODY_FILE
    echo "Best Regards" >> $BODY_FILE
    echo "Admin" >> $BODY_FILE
    $COMMAND -s "${SUBJECT}" -c ${CC_LIST} ${TO_ADDRESS} -- -r ${FROM_ADDRESS} < ${BODY_FILE}
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may lie with using sendmail in that way.  perhaps mail a is better choice

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mail

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sendmail